# What is the type of a constant method pointer?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Given a class

```
class C {
public:
    int f (const int& n) const { return 2*n; }
    int g (const int& n) const { return 3*n; }
};
```

We can define a function pointer `p` to `C::f` like this.

```
int (C::*p) (const int&) const (&C::f);
```

The definition of `p` may be split up using a `typedef`:

```
typedef int (C::*Cfp_t) (const int&) const;
Cfp_t p (&C::f);
```

To make sure `p` doesn't change (as by `p = &C::g;` for instance) we can do:

```
const Cfp_t p (&C::f);
```

Now, what is the type of `p` in this case? And how do we accomplish the last definition of `p` without using a typedef?
I am aware that `typeid (p).name ()` cannot distinguish the outermost const as it yields

```
int (__thiscall C::*)(int const &)const
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the variable `p` is `int (C::*const) (const int&) const`, you can define it without a typedef as:

```
int (C::*const p) (const int&) const = &C::f;
```

Your rule of thumb is: to make the object/type that you're defining const, put the `const` keyword next to the name of the object/type. So you could also do:

```
typedef int (C::*const Cfp_t) (const int&) const;
Cfp_t p(&C::f);
p = &C::f; // error: assignment to const variable
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast and concise answer.